# Can I travel to Romania/Bulgaria when I have used up my Schengen Visa

Tags: schengen, romania, bulgaria

I have type-C multiple entry Schengen visa with a duration of stay of 13 days.
Now that I have used up all 13 days, will I be able to travel to Romania/Bulgaria?

It is stated on their website that:

> Attention! The number of entries as well as the right of stay established as per the Schengen visas must not have been exhausted. The right of stay on the territory of Romania shall not exceed the right of stay granted as per the visas/residence permits issued by the Schengen Member States.

Comment: The quote you give actually answers the question, doesn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your Schengen Visa only allows you to stay 13 days (during which you may enter multiple times) and you have used all 13 days then you have 0 days left.

With that you **cannot** reenter the Schengen Area.

Non-Schengen countries that have this rule, expect you to be **able** to return to the Schengen Area.

Having **exhausted** the amount of days allowed, you cannot use this Visa for a visit to these countries.